# devtools::document() seems not to work

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

Devtools is not building .Rd files in the man directory.

```
git clone https://github.com/az0/mlmeta
cd mlmeta
Rscript -e 'require(devtools);devtools::document()'
```

This gives

```
> require(devtools);document('mlmeta')
Loading required package: devtools
Updating mlmeta documentation
Loading mlmeta
First time using roxygen2 4.0. Upgrading automatically...
```

devtools 1.6.1 (latest from CRAN), R 3.0.2, Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I'm not sure why you're creating that file `document-mlmeta.R`?  Why don't you just run `document()` from inside the root directory of the package, which I imagine would work. E.g. try this in the root of your pkg: `Rscript -e 'devtools::document()'`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thank you. I am updating the question with your elegant suggestion, but the problem remains.

Comment: Looks like you have the wrong syntax. In your .R files use `#'` instead of the `#` followed by a backtick. You also need to name your man file in your `mlmeta.R` file, so add `@name mlmeta` in that file. after that it works for me

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thank you.  This solves the problem.  The only tweak is with Rscript and some of the other .R files I also have to load the method library to avoid an obscure error.